# check if jstl variable is empty by set and out

Tags: java, jstl

hey i wann check if jstl variable is empty by set and out.

created a variable using set:

```
<c:set var="prevValue" value="" />
```

i did the following to check if the jstl variable is empty by using the out method:

```
<c:when test="<c:out value='${empty prevValue}' />" />
empty
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
not empty
</c:otherwise>
```

but i am receiving not empty. why is this so?? i did set prevValue to empty string so techinically this is correct right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code puts a string literal in the `test` attribute of the `c:when` tag, which expects a boolean.  Simplify the test expression to only check that prevValue is empty, the code should not include the `<c:out ...` segment in the test.  Use:

```
<c:when test="${empty prevValue}" />
```

Also if you want to continue using `<c:when>` the conditions must be wrapped in `<c:choose>`

A full example:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty prevValue}" />
        empty
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        not empty
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

Already you have one valid answer,

But why not simply ?

```
<c:if test="${not empty prevValue}">

//not empty 

</c:if>
```